# IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection in Jmeter load test

Tags: oracle, jmeter

I'm doing a load test to Web Service SOAP with Jmeter, on non-GUI mode I start to get errors since 300 Number of Threads, this was detected with a "Response Assertion" with this rule: "Test failed: text expected not to contain /"rta":"FAIL"/".

On GUI mode I can see the error of several samples in "view Results Tree":

> IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

My current configuration of Oracle is:

```
select current_utilization, limit_value 
from v$resource_limit 
where resource_name='sessions';
```

Rta:

```
current_utilization, limit_value
177, 987
```

Cursors

```
select max(a.value) as highest_open_cur, p.value as max_open_cur
  from v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$parameter p
  where a.statistic# = b.statistic# 
  and b.name = 'opened cursors current'
  and p.name= 'open_cursors'
  group by p.value;
```

Rta:

```
  highest_open_cur, max_open_cur
  241, 4000
```

> ¿This error is relate with some configuration in oracle database?

---

More information: ...

Database version:

```
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

Jmeter settings:

```
Inter® Xeon® Gold 6126 CPU @2.6 Ghz 
4 Sockets, 4 Virtual Processors
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
HEAP=-Xms20G -Xmx20G -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m
Windows Server 2016 Standard
```

Test plan:

- Thread Group (Number of Threads 320, Ramp-Up Period 37, Loop Count 1)
- 5 HTTP Request with 1 assertion each one.
- 1 Listener PerfMon Metrics Collector

[image: Server Metrics]

[image: Network]

Comment: Do you have the possibility to bind JMeter to listen on only one NIC? It looks like it is trying to connect to a NIC that is either disabled or non-functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is being thrown by [Oracle JDBC Driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) when it cannot establish connection with the database.

Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127320/java-throw-the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection-on-oracle-afte) of someone suffering from the same problem.

My expectation is that your application is not properly using [Connection Pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) pattern (or it's simply not implemented) so connections are not being closed after executing the query. I would recommend checking your application using a profiler tool like [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/) - this way you will get more clear vision on what's going on.

Another way to get to the bottom of the issue is running a load test against database, i.e. execute queries directly without interim SOAP API calls using JMeter's [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler. This way you will be able to state that database works fine and the problem is with the Java application (or vice versa). See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) to get familiarized with the concept of databases load testing using JMeter.